# fetching data from job portals like naukri.. monster and soo and display in my website

Tags: meteor

I am working on a job portal website...I want to fetch jobs from other job portals and display in my site am using meteor.I have searched a lot but I didn't find any solution can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the job portals from which you want to fetch data exposing their data by REST APIs.

It depends on what you want to do with the data from other sites. If you just want to fetch and show them in your web client without any modification then simple Ajax calls should be fine. If your use case is more complex, say you want fetch, modify, aggregate and store those data then you could use [Meteor HTTP package](https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html) on server side to fetch them then perform further operations.

Comment: I just want to display them .. so it can be done using ajax right .. as u said can you help me what I have to refer to execute that.

Comment: There are many options to do Ajax call in client, but I think jQuery is the easiest way to go check this: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/